# Combining several structural types in python

Tags: python, types, type-hinting, mypy

How do I specify an object that must satisfy several protocols? For instance, suppose I need an object that satisfies both `Reversible` and `Iterable`:

```
from typing import Iterable, Reversible

l = [1, 2, 3]
r: Reversible[int] = l
i: Iterable[int] = l
reversed(r)  # fine
iter(i)  # fine
reversed(i)  # err since not iterable
iter(r)  #err since not reversible
```

I would like to somehow annotate a variable where all operations are possible. For instance (made up syntax):

```
T = TypeVar('T')
ReversibleIterable = Intersection[Reversible[T], Iterable[T]]

ri: ReversibleIterable[int] = l
reversed(ri)  # fine
iter(ri)  # fine
```

Does such a thing exist? I searched for work arounds using protocols, bounded TypeVars, etc. but was unable to make it work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `ReversibleIterable = Intersection[Reversible[T], Iterable[T]]`

There is an old open proposal regarding intersection types: [typing#213](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/213). No approval of it so far.

> I searched for work arounds using protocols

You can indeed introduce your own intersection protocol:

```
_T_co = TypeVar("_T_co", covariant=True)


class ReversibleIt(Reversible[_T_co], Iterable[_T_co], Protocol[_T_co]):
    pass


r: ReversibleIt[int] = [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Works, but requires 3.7 (typing_extensions) or 3.8 (typing). 3.6 with typing extensions throws a runtime error `TypeError: Protocols can only inherit from other protocols, got typing.Reversible`

Comment: Hmm, [cannot reproduce that](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=0.780&python=3.6&gist=22e75399eee37421108b88282b030396). What versions of `mypy`/`typing-extension` do you have installed?