# Intersection of a predefined protocol with a generic protocol

Tags: python, types, type-hinting, mypy, typing

I'm looking for a workaround to the [infamous type `Intersection` problem](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/213) that would apply when one of the protocols is a `TypeVar`.

Pseudocode:

```py
ProtocolT = TypeVar("ProtocolT")

class SupportsEnriched(Protocol):
    ...


def enrich_protocol(target: type[ProtocolT]) → Type[Intersection[ProtocolT, SupportsEnriched]]:
    ...
```

Basically, **the requirement is**: whatever type you pass in, you get that same type back *plus it would support `SupportsEnriched`* too – so this is not a `Union`. `SupportsEnriched` is fine to be a normal class if that's of any help.

I'm aware of the workaround, which involves inheriting a new combined protocol from multiple protocols: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62698797/359730), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74320795/359730), and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74582127/359730). That would result in the following pseudocode:

```py
ProtocolT = TypeVar("ProtocolT")

class SupportsEnriched(Protocol):
    ...


class SupportsGenericEnriched(ProtocolT, SupportsEnriched, Protocol):
    ...
```

Which is certainly impossible due to the `TypeVar` being one of the bases.

Is there any known workaround to fulfil the original requirement?

##### Motivation

The function, I'm trying to type-hint, accepts and inspects a `Protocol` using `inspect.getmembers`. The result is a dynamically generated class, which supports both the provided protocol (its methods get generated on the fly) and a predefined behaviour together.

This is a shared package function, so there's no way to know which protocols will be passed in there.

Comment: Well, you laid out the relevant sources quite neatly. Not sure, what you expect anyone to add here. The specific requirement of having intersection types between type variables and protocols was even explicitly [mentioned](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/213#issuecomment-390613108) in that long issue thread. There is no way to express what you want without a generic intersection construct.

Comment: composition over inheritance may provide a workaround

Comment: I'm not sure this function can be type safe, or at least follow LSP, because I could pass a class that has the same method names as the `SupportsEnriched` but with incompatible meanings. There would be no way to fulfill that contract